# How to find the number of files (not directories) recursively inside a directory, excluding a glob pattern?

Tags: bash, directory, wildcards

I used some aproximation: `tree html | wc -l` but now I require to exclude a glob pattern from the list of found files.

The glob pattern would be something like this: `(node_modules|.git|wp-snapshots)`.

Thank you.

Comment: `find` is the right tool for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `find` for this:

```
find . \( -name .git -o -name node_modules -o -name wp-snapshots \) -prune -o -type f -print | wc -l
```

This looks for all files (including directories) starting from the current directory, and processes them as follows:

- if the name matches `.git`, `node_modules`, or `wp-snapshots`, the tree starting from the matching entry is ignored
- for anything else, regular files are printed

The output is then fed to `wc -l`.